# Clojure: defmulti on different class types

Tags: clojure, signature, method-signature, multimethod

Quick clojure question, I think this is mostly syntax related.  How do I dispatch a multimethod based on specific type signatures of the arguments, for example:

```
(defn foo 
     ([String a String b] (println a b))
     ([Long a Long b] (println (+ a b))
     ([String a Long b] (println a (str b))))
```

I want to extend this to arbitrary stuff, eg two strings followed by a map, to maps followed by a double, two doubles followed by an IFn etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(defn class2 [x y]
  [(class x) (class y)])

(defmulti foo class2)

(defmethod foo [String String] [a b]
  (println a b))

(defmethod foo [Long Long] [a b]
  (println (+ a b)))
```

From the REPL:

```
user=> (foo "bar" "baz")
bar baz
nil
user=> (foo 1 2)
3
nil
```

You could also consider using `type` instead of `class`; `type` returns `:type` metadata, delegating to `class` if there is none.

Also, `class2` does not have to be defined at top level; passing `(fn [x y] ...)` as the dispatch function to `defmulti` is fine too.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `type` instead of `class`, the code will also work in ClojureScript.